# read file but from different activity

Tags: android, android-file

```
String data = "my data";
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("data", MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(data.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

read file but from different activity, any idea? I heard that if I don't define its path, and when I just read it like that, it will auto detect where the file locate, is it true?

back to my question : read file but from different activity HELP！！

Comment: Have you tried reading it from another activity? Did it auto detect where it is located?

Comment: Have you tried reading it from another activity? <-- I've no idea how to do it..

Comment: By activity do you mean application? Each application (by default) stores its files in its own data directory, which is not accessible by  any other application. Activities that are a part of the same application can read eachother's files, because the `openFileOutput()` function points to the same data directory. Please give us more details on what you're trying to do.